# Reference for Khinchine inequality

Tags: probability, reference-request, statistics, inequality

I am looking for the proof of Khinchine inequality (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khintchine_inequality for example), using martingales and the Azuma inequality.

Can you please help me to find a good source?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you state the inequality or link to a place where it is stated?

Comment: Yes, its here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khintchine_inequality